# Load clicked image only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a CSS lightbox gallery on my website, however it loaded the thumbnails and the large images at the same time.

Below are the contents of my various files;

HTML:

```
<div class=galerie>
<a href="#img1" class=galimg><img src=/images/thumbnail.jpg /></a><a href="#_" class=lightbox id="img1"><img data-src="/images/large-image.jpg"></a>
<a href="#img2" class=galimg><img src=/images/thumbnail.jpg /></a><a href="#_" class=lightbox id="img2"><img data-src="/images/large-image.jpg"></a>
<a href="#img3" class=galimg><img src=/images/thumbnail.jpg /></a><a href="#_" class=lightbox id="img3"><img data-src="/images/large-image.jpg"></a>
<a href="#img4" class=galimg><img src=/images/thumbnail.jpg /></a><a href="#_" class=lightbox id="img4"><img data-src="/images/large-image.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lightbox{display:none;position:fixed;z-index:10001;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;top:0;left:0;background:black;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8)}
.lightbox img{max-width:100%;max-height:100%}
.lightbox:target{display:block;outline:none}
```

I've added a script (jQuery):

```
<script>
    $("a.galimg").click(function() {
        $(".lightbox").each(function() {
            $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("data-src"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

And now the large files are loaded only after I click a thumbnail.

The problem is that they all load at once, and I want only the clicked one to load at a time.

Is there a way to do this?

I know the each function does that, is there any other function I could use?

Comment: For one things, there should be quotes for the classes name here `<div class=galerie>` => `<div class="galerie">`. Same thing goes for all the other ones. It may not solve it but it's just proper syntax.

Comment: You are right. The code was minified some time ago, so the quotes were removed. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do something like this (would be easier if you post a link to your site) but i'll try to help.
Just don't use 'each' function. So your code should look something like this:

```
$("a.galimg").click(function() {
    var imgID = $(this).attr('href');
    $(imgID).attr("src", $(this).data('srcbig'));
});
```

And for HTML:

```
<div class=galerie>
    <a href="#img1" class="galimg" data-srcbig="/images/big-img-1.jpg"><img src=/images/thumbnail.jpg /></a><a href="#_" class=lightbox id="img1"><img src="" alt="remember about me"></a>
</div>
```

You could even delete the second 'a href' and image and just create it dynamically. It all depends on how your lightbox library works and what you need.

Comment: The script basically changes the "data-src" to "src" of the second img's with the large images. I will try to implement your code now. Thanks. Here is my website demo with the images: https://www.sorident.ro/en/patients.html

Comment: This was the saving code:    <script>$("a.galimg").click(function(){var t=$(this).attr("href");$(t).find("img").attr("src",$(t).find("img").attr("data-src"))});</script>

Answer (score 0):

Attr sets an attribute, if you're trying to use it, I would go with something like this. I'm not sure what you're trying to set the attribute to, but this is the syntax:

```
<script>
$("a.galimg").click(function() {
        $(this).attr("data-src", "your desired data attribute");
    })
});
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp

Comment: The script basically changes the "data-src" to "src" of the child img's after the parent .galimg is clicked.